# Scala does not throw Exception while testing

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am not able to simulate throwing an Exception in Scala test. Getting error: Expected exception java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but no exception was thrown

```scala
test("test with Exception"){
   val generatorService=mock[GeneratorService]
   val entityProviderRequest=new EntityProviderRequest(entity:Entity)
   when(generatorService.generateVertex(entityProviderRequest.entity, "abc")).thenThrow(new RuntimeException)
   intercept[Exception]{
     generatorService.generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The method you call inside `intercept` is not the same as the one you defined above. That's why it doesn't throw an exception. When the behaviour is not defined, the mock object simply returns `null`. The below test should succeed.

```
test("test with Exception"){
   val generatorService = mock[GeneratorService]
   val entityProviderRequest = new EntityProviderRequest(entity)
   when(generatorService.generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc"))
     .thenThrow(new RuntimeException)

   intercept[Exception]{
     generatorService.generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc")
   }
}
```

---

**Update**

If you want to use the real implementation of a method, but mock the others, you can achieve it by using `when(..).thenCallRealMethod()`:

```
test("test with Exception"){
   val generatorService = mock[GeneratorService]
   val entityProviderRequest = new EntityProviderRequest(entity)

   when(generatorService.generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc"))
     .thenCallRealMethod()
   when(generatorService.generateVertex(entityProviderRequest.entity, "abc"))
     .thenThrow(new RuntimeException)


   intercept[Exception]{
     generatorService.generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc")
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually generateVertex(entityProviderRequest.entity, "abc") is getting called from inside generateElements(entityProviderRequest, "abc"), How to throw exception in this scenario?

Comment: Ah ok, normally when you mock a class, it means you replace the whole implementation of the it with the mock instance, so your `generateElements` implementation which calls `generateVertex` is completely replaced, but you can explicitly tell mockito to use the real implementation for `generateElements`, please check the updated answer